# Multisite without .htaccess

Tags: multisite, htaccess, ssl, virtual-hosts

Do I need to use `.htaccess` file for a multisite? I have setup basic wordpress site and configured it with apache2 VirtualHost as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    RewriteEngine On
    Options FollowSymLinks

    # THIS REDIRECTS TO HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/
    <Directory /var/www/example/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/
    <Directory /var/www/example/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I follow the steps to enable multisite, wordpress prompts me to paste these options to my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

But I do not have an `.htaccess` file. However If I make it, and configure apache, rewrite rules do not work, e.g. `example.com/wp-admin` is not rewritten into `wp-admin/` with a trailing slash, but into ugly long link: `https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`. Can this be because of SSL rewrite rules? My questions are: do I need `.htaccess`? And how do I make its rewrite rules work?

Comment: If you are using Apache and even have `AllowOverride` active, what is the problem with using a .htaccess file?

Comment: I just want to have everything in one file if possible. But even then, when I configure VHost with `AccessFileName .htaccess` I do not see that link to wp-admin is rewritten.

Comment: That admin link is the same one that's given even if pretty urls are on. Why would it matter if an admin URL (Which isn't indexed by search engines anyway) is not pretty?
You can paste those rules into your virtualhosts config if you don't want  a .htaccess file but you'll find your life a whole lot easier if you allow for one.

Comment: @SteveNorth yes, I have been reading, it's easier to have one. I will just include SSL redirection in .htaccess.

Comment: Are you hosting multiple domains with this VirtualHost - if not then your redirection to HTTPS should be simplified to use a mod_alias `Redirect` instead. Also, are you really on Apache 2.2?

Comment: @MrWhite I'm using `Apache/2.4.18` and I'm not sure yet about multiple domains, as that decision is not up to me, and not yet made. I've configured redirection in `.htaccess`:

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wpinstance.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

If however I need multiple domains, I can easily create new `<VirtualHost>` files for them :)

Comment: I've updated my answer below with a small change required for Apache 2.4+. My comment regarding the use of a mod_alias `Redirect` is only relevant if you are performing this redirect in your VirtualHost (not `.htaccess`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> e.g. `wpinstance.com/wp-admin` is not rewritten into `wp-admin/` with a trailing slash, but into ugly long link: `https://wpinstance.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwpinstance.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

As is already mentioned in comments, this is intentional. There is no "pretty" URL for this. And neither does there need to be - this should not be indexed or linked to.

> do I need `.htaccess`?

No, you don't "need" `.htaccess`.

If you have access to the server config, then you can paste these directives verbatim inside the `<Directory /var/www/wpinstance/>` container (inside the `<VirtualHost *:443>` container).

However, to paste those directives directly inside the `<VirtualHost>` container you would need to make several changes, since mod_rewrite behaves differently in a *server* context (as opposed to a *directory* or `.htaccess` context).

Note that everytime you make changes to the server config then you will need to restart Apache. You don't need to restart Apache when you change the `.htaccess` file.

I would also consider disabling `MultiViews` - unless you specifically require this for something? ie. Remove `MultiViews` from the `Options` directive. (MultiViews can conflict with mod_rewrite - depends what you are doing.)

If you are not going to use `.htaccess` files then they should be disabled:

```
AllowOverride None
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I'm using Apache/2.4.18

Note that the `Order` and `Allow` directives are deprecated in Apache 2.4, and will be removed in future versions. You need to change the following (Apache 2.2 and earlier) directives:

> ```
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
> ```

to read:

```
Require all granted
```

in Apache 2.4+

Comment: Thank you very much on the advices, especially the `MultiVIews`. I've decided to keep `.htaccess` because it seems easier. I have moved https redirection from `<VirtualHost>` into `.htaccess` also.

Comment: Although my domain does not get rewritten from `wpinstance.com` to `wpinstance.com/index.php` as the rules of `.htaccess` imply.

Comment: Is your site not working? Your `.htaccess` rules don't actually perform that specific rewrite (from the document root) - note the single dot (`.`) regex. This "rewrite" is left for mod_dir instead (mod_dir will issue a subrequest for the directory index by default).

Comment: Sorry, I used wpinstance instead of example.com, but it turned out wpinstance.com exists, and I'm not the owner of it. Yes my site works. Thank fot that info, it seems that I don't yet quite understand how htaccess and rewrite work. But redirection to https works from htaccess, so I guess everything works just fine :)

Comment: The _internal_ "rewrite" to `index.php` is entirely server-side (internal to the server) - there is no change to the URL the user sees in the browser (unlike a "redirect"), if that is what you were expecting. (Yes, always best to use `example.com` for example URLs. You can still edit this into your question. Although I hadn't tried to access `wpinstance.com`.)

Comment: Thank you ^__^ I will change the apache file according to updated answer. And will edit to example.com my question.